# Get a blank page when view php-fpm staus on multiple pool config

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am trying to enable the nginx and php-fpm status page. I am able to get nginx status page working, but not the php-fpm. I have one site on the server, but two php-fpm pools. I have restarted nginx and php-fpm, when I view the http://my_domain/www0_status page, it gives a blank page. The nginx access log shows http status code with 200.

The config in php-fpm www0.conf:

```
 pm.status_path = /www0_status
```

The config in php-fpm www1.conf:

```
 pm.status_path = /www1_status
```

The config in nginx.conf:

```
    # Monitor www0 pool
    location /www0_status {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow my_ip;
        deny all;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Monitor www1 pool
    location /www1_status {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow my_ip;
        deny all;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The nginx access log:

```
 my_ip - - [10/Jul/2015:15:09:34 -0700] "GET /www0_status HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0" "-"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this variable in status location:

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

Comment: This works. Ｉhad this line for all php files, but didn't know the status page also need it. Thank you!